# Binary operator '<=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'UILabel?' and 'Double'

Tags: ios, swift

Binary operator '<=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'UILabel?' and 'Double'

```
@objc func calculate() {
    if let yourHeightTxtField = yourHeightTxtField.text, let yourWeightTxtField = yourWeightTxtField.text {

        if let height = Double(yourHeightTxtField), let weight = Double(yourWeightTxtField) {
            view.endEditing(true)
            Percentile.isHidden = false
            numOfPercentile.isHidden = false
            numOfPercentile.text = "\(BMI.getPercentile(forWeight: weight, andHeight: height))"
        }
    }
    if (numOfPercentile <= 18.5) {
        Percentile.text = "you are underweight"
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear. `numOfPrecentile` is a `UILabel?`.  You can't compare that to a `Double`.  Perhaps you want to store your calculation into a `Double` first before setting `numOfPercentile.text`.

Comment: start var names with small letter

Comment: Stevenjparrett, welcome to stackoverflow. Please don't replace your question with garbage. If your question has been answered to your satisfaction, click the check mark next to the answer. There is no apparent reason to delete this question, but if you want to delete it, click the “delete” link under the question. If that doesn't work for some reason, click the “flag” link instead and choose “in need of moderator intervention” to ask for help from a moderator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is pretty clear. `numOfPrecentile` is a `UILabel?`. You can't compare that to a `Double`. I would suggest storing your calculation into a `Double` first before setting `numOfPercentile.text`.

```
@objc func calculate() {
    if let yourHeightTxtField = yourHeightTxtField.text, let yourWeightTxtField = yourWeightTxtField.text {

        if let height = Double(yourHeightTxtField), let weight = Double(yourWeightTxtField) {
            view.endEditing(true)
            percentile.isHidden = false
            numOfPercentile.isHidden = false
            let bmi = BMI.getPercentile(forWeight: weight, andHeight: height)
            numOfPercentile.text = "\(bmi)"
            if bmi <= 18.5 {
                percentile.text = "you are underweight"
            }
        }
    }
}
```